# Форма регистрации php > MySQL (размер первой буквы)

Tags: mysql, php, база-данных, регистрация

На сайте есть простая форма регистрации. Мы вводим некие данные в нашем случае (логин пароль) и они попадают к нам в бд. Но! Попав в бд данные логина преобразуются в текст с маленькими буквами. То есть: Пишем Yellkow, а в бд записывается как yellkow. Мне посоветовали использовать вот это:

```
update `таблица` set `столбец`=concat(upper(left(`столбец`,1)),substr(`столбец`,2));
```

Я без понятия как это использовать. И как я понимаю, следующие записи будут опять с маленьким регистром. Помогите.

- Форма регистрации: getocraft.tk/registration/
- Вид бд:

[image]

Как сделать, чтобы первая буква была большой автоматически? Заранее благодарю за любую помощь.

Форма регистрации:

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK', true);
echo '<h2>Регистрация</h2>';
include "connect.php";
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $login  = $_POST['login'];
    $pass   = $_POST['passwd'];
    $repass = $_POST['repasswd'];

    $login  = addslashes(strtolower(trim($login)));
    $pass   = addslashes(strtolower(trim($pass)));
    $repass = addslashes(strtolower(trim($repass)));

    if (empty($login) || empty($pass) || empty($repass)) {
        echo 'Не все поля заполнены.';
    }

    elseif (ereg("[^0-9a-zA-Z_-]", $login, $Txt)) {
        echo "Логин введен не корректно.";
    } elseif (ereg("[^0-9a-zA-Z_-]", $pass, $Txt)) {
        echo "Пароль введен не корректно.";
    } elseif (ereg("[^0-9a-zA-Z_-]", $repass, $Txt)) {
        echo "Повтор пароля введен не корректно.";
    }

    else {
        $login_proverka = mysql_query("SELECT $db_columnUser FROM $db_table WHERE $db_columnUser='$login'") or ("Запрос к базе завершился ощибкой.");

        if (mysql_num_rows($login_proverka)) {
            echo "Акаунт <b>" . $login . "</b> уже существует.";
        } elseif ((strlen($login) < 4) or (strlen($login) > 8)) {
            echo "Логин должен содержать не меньше 4 символов и не больше 8.";
        } elseif ((strlen($pass) < 4) or (strlen($pass) > 15)) {
            echo "Пароль должен содержать не меньше 4 символов и не больше 15.";
        } elseif ((strlen($repass) < 4) or (strlen($repass) > 15)) {
            echo "Повтор пароля должен содержать не меньше 4 символов и не больше 15.";
        } elseif ($pass != $repass) {
            echo "Пароли не совпадают.";
        } else {
            $cp = md5($pass);
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO $db_table ($db_columnUser,$db_columnPass) VALUES('$login','$cp')") or die("Запрос к базе завершился ощибкой.");
            echo 'Аккаунт <b>' . $login . '</b> успешно зарегестрирован.';

        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <p><br/>Логин:<br/><input name=login type=text/><br/></p>
    <p><br/>Пароль:<br/><input name=passwd type=password/><br/></p>
    <p><br/>Повторите пароль:<br/><input name=repasswd type=password/><br/></p>
    <p><br/><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить"/><br/></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вникал в весь код, но чтобы буквы оставались такими как есть уберите [strtolower](http://www.php.su/functions/?strtolower) в первых строчках

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Всё заработало. Не думал что ответ так прост. Не могу передать свою благодарность.

Comment: Плюсани ответ )